# AttributeError: 'myThread' object has no attribute '_initialized'

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

Any idea why I get the following error when running the code below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pytests\mthread1.py", line 25, in <module>
    thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
  File "C:\pytests\mthread1.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.name = name
AttributeError: 'myThread' object has no attribute '_initialized'
```

Code:

```
import time
import threading

exitFlag = 0

class myThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
            self.threadID = threadID
            self.name = name
            self.counter = counter
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        def run(self):  
            print("Starting ", self.name)
            print_time(self.name, self.counter, 5)
            print("Exiting ", self.name)

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
    while counter:
        if exitFlag:
            thread.exit()
        time.sleep(delay)
        print("{}: {}" . format(threadName, time.ctime(time.time())))
        counter -= 1

thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 2)

thread1.start()         
thread2.start()         

print("Exiting Main Thread")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simple, according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

> > A thread has a name. The name can be passed to the constructor, and read or changed through the name attribute.

and

```
class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={})
```

So, you are trying to set an attribute which is probably expected to be set in certain manner, through the class constructor. In fact, if you check the `Thread` class' [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/acf6ffc57fcf/Lib/threading.py):

```
@property
def name(self):
    assert self._initialized, "Thread.__init__() not called"
    return self._name

@name.setter
def name(self, name):
    assert self._initialized, "Thread.__init__() not called"
    self._name = str(name)
```

All you have to change - call `Thread.__init__(name=name)` a bit earlier:

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name=name)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.counter = counter
```

Comment: Alternatively, don't override `__init__` or subclass `Thread` at all. Almost always, passing the right `target` (plus `args`) is sufficient, and simpler to boot.

Comment: @delnan I'd suggest posting that as an answer :) Many people are yet to come and look for what you've suggested.